# When does $F'(c)$ exist? When does $F'(c) = f(c)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

If $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R} $ is Riemann integrable, we may define the function $F : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt
$$
The first fundamental theorem of calculus says that if $f$ is continuous at $c \in (a,b)$, then $F'(c) = f(c)$.

If $f$ is not continuous at $c$, then $F'(c)$ can fail to exist, and, if it does exist, it can happen that $F'(c) \neq f(c)$.

I'm wondering if there are easily stated necessary and sufficient conditions for when:

1. $F'(c)$ exists.
2. $F'(c) = f(c)$.

---

I've given this a little thought, but all I can see is that we have the following equivalences:

1. $F'(c)$ exists $\iff$ $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_c^{c + h} f(t) dt}{h}$ exists
2. $F' (c) = f(c) \iff \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_c^{c + h} \left[f(t) - f(c)\right] dt}{h} = 0$

These of course are necessary and sufficient conditions, but, to my knowledge, they don't have a special name. Morally, 1 says that averages of $f$ don't "blow up" as intervals get smaller, and 2 says that $f$ is continuous "in the mean." Is there a named condition equivalent to 1 or 2?

Comment: It is really very tricky to figure out if $F'(c) $ exists. If the function $f$ has one sided limit at $c$ then same sided derivative of $F$ at $c$ exists. If these one sided limits (left and right)  of $f$ don't match then the derivative $F'(c) $ does not exist. The problem is challenging when $f$ has an oscillatory discontinuity at $c$. It may or may not happen that $F'(c) $ exist. Further since the value of integral does not depend on value of $f$ at a single point $c$, the relation $F'(c) =f(c) $ loses its significance when $f$ is discontinuous at $c$.

Comment: For oscillatory case we have $f(0)=0,f(x)=\sin(1/x),x\neq 0$ and $F'(0)=0$. Note that we can keep value of $f(0)$ arbitrary without any impact on $F, F'$ and then the relation $F'(0)=f(0)$ will not hold.